# Grails Security Plugin - Expiration time

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-session

I have this plugin in my dependencies, Grails 3.2.2:

```
dependencies{
    ... 
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.2'
    ...
}
```

And I want to change the expiration time of the token for a certain `UserRole`, is it possible? if it is, where should I change this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to go with token approach. I would recommend to use `spring-security-rest` plugin. and change token time.

Comment: Is it secure to change from one plugin to the other one? Or should I make some changes @UsmanRana

Comment: `spring-security-core` will be used under the layer. `spring-security-rest` will be there to make configurations for different things like `token` in your case.
And yeah, there won't be any issue with this

Comment: And you can set token expiry date like `grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.expiration = 36000`

Comment: so I can have both plugins? I don't have to replace `spring-security-core`? @UsmanRana

Comment: yes. That's it.